# Dar estilos a dos divs dentro de un div global CSS

Tags: css, div

Tengo un **div A** que contiene al **div B** y al **div C**.

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B">
       ...
    </div>
    <div id="C">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Deseo que el div B tenga una separación margin-top: 2em; respecto a div C.**

El siguiente código no me funciona:

```
#B + #C{
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: No tienes ningún `div C` en tu ejemplo, aunque supongo que será un error al transcribirlo. De todas formas el selector #B + #C aplica al `div C` no al `div B`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente regla de selectores universales `> *`, automáticamente añaden el margen al siguiente elemento adyacente o a todo lo que esté englobado dentro del `div` es decir alude a todos los elementos que están contenidos dentro de otro.

```
#A > * {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

o

```
#B > * {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

También puedes aplicar aquella regla que estas usando pero separándolas por comas:

```
#B, #C {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el estilo es especifico para ciertos identificadores, ¿por qué no escribes la regla para el identificador 'C'?, es decir:

```
#C {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Pero claro, deberías evitar escribir reglas de estilo para los identificadores y acostumbrarte a hacerlo en clases, por ejemplo:

```css
.container-box > div {  
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.container-box > div:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div>
    DIV B
  </div>
  <div>  
    DIV C
  </div>
  <div>  
    DIV D
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Es una "buena práctica" usar clases para aplicar estilos y reservar las IDs para su uso con JS. Saludos.